# Unable to get login using laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I'm developing user authentication on basis of SOAP API response using Laravel 5.4, for that I've implemented `UserProvider` and `AuthServiceProvider` but still unsuccessful.
Here is the implementation of `UserProvider`

```
namespace App\Authentication;

use App\Http\Controllers\ApiCallsController;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider as IlluminateUserProvider;
use Config;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User;

class UserProvider implements IlluminateUserProvider
{
    /**
     * @param  mixed $identifier
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
     */
    public function retrieveById($identifier)
    {
        // Get and return a user by their unique identifier
        $http_client = new ApiCallsController();
        $check_user = $http_client->HttpClient("GET", Config::get('constants.c2mCloud') . '/user/UserTypeOrName/' . $identifier);
        $users = json_decode($check_user);
        if ($users->responseCode == "00") {
            if (count($users->users) > 0) {
                $user = new User();
                $users = $users->users[0];
                $user->id = $users->userId;
                $user->c2MUsername = $users->c2MUsername;
                $user->createdAt = $users->createdAt;
                $user->lastModifiedAt = $users->lastModifiedAt;
                $user->password = $users->password;
                $user->userType = $users->userType;
                $user->active = $users->active;
                return new \App\User([
                    'id' => $users->userId
                    ]);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param  mixed $identifier
     * @param  string $token
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
     */
    public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token)
    {
        // Get and return a user by their unique identifier and "remember me" token
    }

    /**
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable $user
     * @param  string $token
     * @return void
     */
    public function updateRememberToken(Authenticatable $user, $token)
    {
        // Save the given "remember me" token for the given user
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve a user by the given credentials.
     *
     * @param  array $credentials
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
     */
    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
    {
        // Get and return a user by looking up the given credentials
        $http_client = new ApiCallsController();
        $check_user = $http_client->HttpClient("GET", Config::get('constants.c2mCloud') . '/user/UserTypeOrName/' . $credentials['c2MUsername']);
        $users = json_decode($check_user);
        if ($users->responseCode == "00") {
            if (count($users->users) > 0) {
                $users = $users->users[0];
//                return $users->users[0];
                return new \App\User([
                    'id' => $users->userId,
//                    'c2MUsername' => $users->c2MUsername,
//                    'createdAt' => $users->createdAt,
//                    ''
                ]);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Validate a user against the given credentials.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable $user
     * @param  array $credentials
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validateCredentials(Authenticatable $user, array $credentials)
    {
        // Check that given credentials belong to the given user
    }

}
```

And implementation of `AuthServiceProvider`

```
<?php
namespace App\Authentication;
use Auth;
use App\Authentication\UserProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Perform post-registration booting of services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Auth::provider('c2m_provider', function($app, array $config) {
            return new UserProvider();
        });
    }
    /**
     * Register bindings in the container.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

and my `User` class is

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;

class User implements Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */

    public function getAuthIdentifierName()
    {
        // Return the name of unique identifier for the user (e.g. "id")
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        // Return the unique identifier for the user (e.g. their ID, 123)
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        // Returns the (hashed) password for the user
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        // Return the token used for the "remember me" functionality
    }

    /**
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        // Store a new token user for the "remember me" functionality
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        // Return the name of the column / attribute used to store the "remember me" token
    }
}
```

And in my controller after using `Auth::login($user);` when I check is user logged in by `Auth::check()` it alwys return false.

Anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For custom Authentication, we need in to implement these 4 classes in laravel 5.4. And this implementation is working for me in a live project.

```
namespace App\Auth;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as User_Authenticatable;

class Authenticatable implements User_Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The column name of the "remember me" token.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $rememberTokenName = 'remember_token';

    /**
     * Get the name of the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifierName()
    {
        return "id";
    }

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->{$this->getAuthIdentifierName()};
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the token value for the "remember me" session.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        if (! empty($this->getRememberTokenName())) {
            return $this->{$this->getRememberTokenName()};
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the token value for the "remember me" session.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        if (! empty($this->getRememberTokenName())) {
            $this->{$this->getRememberTokenName()} = $value;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the column name for the "remember me" token.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        return $this->rememberTokenName;
    }

}
```

2nd

```
namespace App\Auth;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as User_Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate;

Class Authorizable Implements User_Authorizable
{
    /**
     * Determine if the entity has a given ability.
     *
     * @param  string  $ability
     * @param  array|mixed  $arguments
     * @return bool
     */
    public function can($ability, $arguments = [])
    {
        return app(Gate::class)->forUser($this)->check($ability, $arguments);
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the entity does not have a given ability.
     *
     * @param  string  $ability
     * @param  array|mixed  $arguments
     * @return bool
     */
    public function cant($ability, $arguments = [])
    {
        return ! $this->can($ability, $arguments);
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the entity does not have a given ability.
     *
     * @param  string  $ability
     * @param  array|mixed  $arguments
     * @return bool
     */
    public function cannot($ability, $arguments = [])
    {
        return $this->cant($ability, $arguments);
    }
}
```

3rd

```
namespace App\Auth;


use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword as ResetPasswordNotification;

class CanResetPassword extends ResetPasswordNotification
{

}
```

4th

```
<?php

namespace App\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\ApiCallsController;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider as IlluminateUserProvider;
use Config;
use App\Models\ApiUser;

class UserProvider implements IlluminateUserProvider
{
    /**
     * @param  mixed $identifier
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
     */
    public function retrieveById($identifier)
    {
        // Get and return a user by their unique identifier
        return ApiUser::getUser(null, null, $identifier);
    }

    /**
     * @param  mixed $identifier
     * @param  string $token
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
     */
    public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token)
    {
        // Get and return a user by their unique identifier and "remember me" token
    }

    /**
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable $user
     * @param  string $token
     * @return void
     */
    public function updateRememberToken(Authenticatable $user, $token)
    {
        // Save the given "remember me" token for the given user
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve a user by the given credentials.
     *
     * @param  array $credentials
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
     */
    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
    {
        // Get and return a user by looking up the given credentials
        return ApiUser::getUser($credentials['c2MUsername']);
    }

    /**
     * Validate a user against the given credentials.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable $user
     * @param  array $credentials
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validateCredentials(Authenticatable $user, array $credentials)
    {
        // Check that given credentials belong to the given user
        $api_user = \App\Models\ApiUser::getUser($credentials['c2MUsername']);
        if(!empty($api_user)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

My Custom Auth Provider

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: CresenTech
 * Date: 23-Oct-17
 * Time: 7:19 PM
 */
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Auth\UserProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class CustomAuthProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
//    protected $policies = [
////        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
//    ];

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        /**
         * Register any authentication / authorization services.
         *
         * @return void
         */
//        $this->registerPolicies();

        Auth::provider('custom',function()
        {
            return new UserProvider();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

}
```

And my auth.php in config directory

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Defaults
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
| reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
| as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
|
*/

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Guards
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
| Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
| here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| Supported: "session", "token"
|
*/

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
 //
 //        'c2m' => [
 //            'driver' => 'session',
 //            'provider' => 'users',
 //        ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
| sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
| be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

'providers' => [

//        'users' => [
//            'driver' => 'eloquent',
//            'model' => App\User::class,
//        ],

    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'custom',
    ],


//         'users' => [
//             'driver' => 'database',
//             'table' => 'users',
//         ],
 ],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Resetting Passwords
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
| than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
| separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
|
| The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
| considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
| they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
|
*/

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
//            'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Auth::attempt($username,$password)

```
if (Auth::attempt($username,$password)) {
  //user is logged in
} else {
  //user is not logged in
}
```

Auth::check() simply checks if the user is logged in.  It doesn't actually process the login.

Comment: Yeah I use “\Auth::login($user);” to login after it I check that is user get logged in or not..... for that I use \Auth::check(); and it return false. And It worked fine for me when I have attached data base with system. Now we are moving system from database to APIs... So, now problem occurs